# How to fix PHPMailer Password command failed issue?

Tags: php, hosting, phpmailer

I am using Hostinger. I just got an email through them. I keep getting the following error..

2023-11-30 18:58:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2023-11-30 18:58:51 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed..

I used the correct username and password in the actual code.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing [ICODE]true[/ICODE] enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'no-reply@example.com';
$mail->Password   = 'thePassword';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 587;

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('no-reply@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
// $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Comment: Judging by the instructions here https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/4305847-set-up-hostinger-email-on-your-applications-and-devices you must have missed something. The password might be correct but the port, for example, is wrong and doesn't support sending mail through it. This might also be helpful: https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/4725594-how-to-set-up-the-easy-wp-smtp-plugin-on-wordpress if nothing helps and you're sure you've set things up correctly -- contact support, maybe your account is restricted for SMTP?

Comment: Please show the rest of the SMTP debug output as it might contain additional clues.